How can I change the `ls` color for mounted folders, `dircolors` does not seem to have a mapping?
I spent some time with the dircolors man page today and have been able to adjust the colors for various file system elements. [directories, folders, links]
I've also noticed that directories which are mounted to other file systems are not the same mapping as directories. Furthermore I cannot find a way to map these because they don't seem to be mapped by dircolors at all.
The following folders are mounted, and show up dark-blue with an underline:
~/data                -> /dev/sdb1 (secondary SSD)
/mnt/contoso/files     -> DFS Share: //contoso.local/files
/mnt/contoso/projects -> DFS Share: //contoso.local/projects


I've changed:

di: directory
ln: link
so: socket
do: door

But none of those altered the colors of these mounted directories. I printed all of the dircolors --print-ls-colors in attempt to find which setting matched the color of these mounted directories. As you can see, none of the options match the color of the mounted directories. Is there another tool which is responsible for coloring mounted directories, other than LS_COLORS / dircolors?
I'm surprised to find there is not already a mapping for them here, it seems like the proper scope, to me, to be looking for this.

There is no option in GNU ls to identify directories¹ that are mount points.
Determining whether a file is a mountpoint involves comparing the device id with that of its parent directory², which is not something ls does. The mountpoint command does.
ls exposes the information reported by stat()/lstat()/statx() (all attributes of the inodes such as type, size, timestamp, ownership, permissions...), the targets of symlinks (readlink())  about the presence of other security attributes such as ACLs or capabilities though usually not details about them. GNU ls on Linux can give you SELinux / SMACK security context. But that's about it.
Out of those, only a subset can be used as basis for colouring, mostly name and stat() info.
If using zsh, what you could do is mark directory mountpoints in a directory listing by appending a / to them in a glob qualifier function and not add the -p/-F option to ls or zsh's M qualifier (which themselves add / to all directories):
mark_mountpoints() {
  if [[ -d $REPLY && ! -L $REPLY ]] && mountpoint -q -- $REPLY; then
    REPLY+=/
  fi
}

Then use for instance ls -ld -- *(+mark_mountpoints) instead of ls -l.
Here, in /, that gives:
$ ls -ld -- *(+mark_mountpoints)
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Jun 27  2021 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4096 Aug 16 07:10 boot/
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root 3740 Aug 17 07:08 dev/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 5110 Aug 17 07:07 etc
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   52 Nov 18  2022 home/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   28 Aug 16 07:08 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-6.10.3-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   28 Aug 16 07:08 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-6.9.12-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Jun 27  2021 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Jun 27  2021 lib32 -> usr/lib32
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Jun 27  2021 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   10 Jun 27  2021 libx32 -> usr/libx32
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   48 Jul 11  2022 media
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root    2 Mar 24  2023 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   20 Feb 23 11:15 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 371 root root    0 Aug 17 07:07 proc/
drwx------   1 root root  470 Aug 16 08:17 root
drwxr-xr-x  36 root root 1020 Aug 17 07:53 run/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    8 Jun 27  2021 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   12 May 12 17:26 snap
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Jun 27  2021 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Aug 17 07:40 sys/
drwxrwxrwt  18 root root  480 Aug 17 07:58 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  116 Jun 27  2021 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  114 May 12 10:21 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   25 Aug 16 07:08 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-6.10.3-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   25 Aug 16 07:08 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-6.9.12-amd64

It doesn't look like you can set a colour for those files with a trailing / though.
On some systems, you can get a clue as to whether a directory is a mountpoint by adding the -i option which displays the inode number.
For instance, on Linux-based systems, the inode number of the root directory of an ext4 file system is often 2, and that of a tmpfs and virtual FS 1. For other types of filesystems, YMMV.
$ ls -ai
     256 .       13851156 initrd.img          7242 opt          1 tmp
     256 ..      13851154 initrd.img.old         1 proc       457 usr
     456 bin          461 lib                 2044 root       269 var
       2 boot         463 lib32                  1 run   13851155 vmlinuz
  175919 .cache       465 lib64                459 sbin  13851153 vmlinuz.old
       1 dev          467 libx32          12535405 snap
     260 etc          262 media               7241 srv
     256 home        7240 mnt                    1 sys

Where boot is the mountpoint of an ext4 FS, tmp/dev of a tmpfs, proc/sys of virtual FS, and / (. and .. in that listing) of a btrfs FS subvol (here with 256 as the inode number).

¹ or other types of files as mount points don't have to be directory; for instance you can bind-mount files over other files.
² or compute the full path and compare with contents of /proc/self/mounts which isn't foolproof either.
